# MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, 2007, sharepoint-server

I am very excited for my current work as I am migrating moss 2003 to SharePoint 2013.Can any one help me is there any way to directly migrate with out any tools or Is there windows explorer view option in Moss 2007

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of these tools:

- Metalogix
- Avepoint
- Sharegate
- Metavis

There are other tools as well. With the explorer view, you can not migrate metadata.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct path between SharePoint 2003 and SharePoint 2013.  There is also not a direct path between MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2013.  Your best bet would be to use one of the aforementioned 3rd party content migration tools.  In most cases, you may be able to get your content migrated but custom page templates may not migrate at all.